# Steps to setup SP2016 onprem with React using SPFX

Tags: 2016, spfx-webparts, nodejs

I am trying to setup SP2016 onprem with React, using Yoeman generator 
`@microsoft/sharepoint`.

I am getting errors when I run `gulp serve`.

Need Help on setting up this project using SPFX.

I have raised a github issue as well, kindly check it for more info : [Link](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3621)

Kindly, please share latest steps to be used for setting up SP2016 onprem with React.

*** UPDATE ***
Error being generated :

> Error - typescript - src\webparts\helloWorld\HelloWorldWebPart.ts(7,7): error 
>     TS2307: Cannot find module '@microsoft/sp-property-pane'.
>     Error - 'typescript' sub task errored after 6.45 s
>     "TypeScript error(s) occurred."

Comment: Looks like there is regression in the new release. Can you reinstall the generator using `npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.7.1` and then create a webpart for 2016 and check ?

Comment: I started with 1.7.1 version only. Even that was not working for me

Comment: Quite strange, can you try with `npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.6.0` and check ?

Comment: will try that one.

Comment: @GautamSheth , i tried with V1.6.0 generator. There were no errors, but the site was not loading with just gulp serve. But with following command, set NODE_NO_HTTP2=1 && gulp serve , I was able to load the site.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Gautam Sheth 's comment,

I implemented following steps and was able to load SP2016 onprem using react Site without any errors, :

- npm list -g --depth 0
- npm uninstall -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
- npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.6.0
- yo @microsoft/sharepoint --skip-install
- gave answers to the prompts for SP2016 onprem with react using spfx
- npm i
- made a change for following warning :
    Warning - tslint - src\webparts\helloWorld\components\HelloWorld.tsx(16,23): error 
    quotemark: " should be '
- set NODE_NO_HTTP2=1 && gulp serve

Works for V1.7.0 (@microsoft/generator-sharepoint) of the yoeman generator as well.

For V1.7.1 and V1.8.0,  @microsoft/generator-sharepoint , were not generating error free SP2016 onprem with React solution. Support for this on the latest versions would be appreciated greatly.